Lime-Haxe: Error: Could not find build target "default"
I'm trying to compile FNF: Psych Engine and I tried to rebuild the library hxvlc using
haxelib run lime rebuild hxvlc windows but it doesn't work.
Every time I run the command I got this error.
Error: Could not find build target "default"

I don't know if this issue is related with hxcpp or the library Build.xml
(also, I tried to rebuild hxCodec as well and it didn't work too)
